# Using Selenium in Python to click/select a radio button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select from a list of 3 buttons, but can't find a way to select them.  Below is the HTML I am working with.

```
<input name="pollQuestion" type="radio" value="SRF"> 
    <font face="arial,sans-serif" size="-1">ChoiceOne</font><br />
<input name="pollQuestion" type="radio" value="COM">
    <font face="arial,sans-serif" size="-1">ChoiceTwo</font><br />
<input name="pollQuestion" type="radio" value="MOT">
    <font face="arial,sans-serif" size="-1">ChoiceThree</font>
```

I can find it by using the following code:

```
for i in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='radio']"):
     print i.get_attribute("value")
```

This outputs: SRF,COM,MOT

But I would like to select ChoiceOne.  (To click it)  How do I do this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use CSS Selector or XPath to select by `value` attribute directly, then click it.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='SRF']").click()
# browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@type='radio' and @value='SRF']").click()
```

Corrections (but OP should learn how to look up in documentation)

- In Python binding, `find_elements_by_css` doesn't exist, it's called `find_elements_by_css_selector`. One should be able to look at the exception message and look back into documentation [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py) and figure out why.
- Notice the difference between `find_element_by_css_selector` and `find_elements_by_css_selector`? The first one finds the first matching element, the second one finds a list, so you need to use [0] to index. [Here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py) is the API documentation. The reason why I use the latter, is because I copied your code, which I shouldn't.

Comment: WebDriver has no attribute 'find_elements_by_css'.  I would prefer to use CSS, as I am taking it from CSS, but found more success adding [0] to the 2nd entry.

Comment: actually it's `find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='SRF']").click()`

Comment: @sspross Yes, exactly. I just went ahead and edited the post so that it presents code that actually works.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Selenium webdriver Radio button click

When i used xpath :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='id_gender2']").click()
```

radio button not selected

But I used css_selector :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#id_gender1").click()
```

radio button selected

Answer (score 3):

`find_elements_by_css_selector` worked for me,

```
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='SRF']")[0].click()
```

Comment: that works. What I think is even better: Use `find_element` instead of `find_elements`. Then you don't get a list back so you don't have to get the element with [0]. So it would be `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='SRF']").click()`

Answer (score 1):

First Radio button was not selected for me also. But after inserting Time it works for me.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("login").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("email_create").send_keys("testsel000@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("SubmitCreate").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#id_gender2").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you have a radio button to select either of the two options, "Male or "Female". Then try using the following :- This is in Python (Selenium).

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Male')]").click()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. OP has provided their own code, and it would be much more helpful if you referred to that code when answering instead of making up your own example.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//input[@type='radio' and @value='SRF']")[0].click
```

This ended up being the fix.  I was getting errors without the [0] there, that a list does not have a click() attribute (even though there was only 1 match).  Thanks for the help user1177636!

Comment: In this case, you could have used browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@type='radio' and @value='SRF']").click()

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach if there's only those radio buttons on the whole page (as in my case),

```
folder = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@type='radio']")
folder[i].click()
```

You can give the index of the radio button you want to select and it will be selected. Or you can play with it to get your job done.