# Selenium- Selecting Radio Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium in Python3 to select a radio button
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlQ3n.png). And below is the code I'm using to select the radio button but it doesn't work.

```
    emailElem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('SSR_DUMMY_RECV1$sels$0')
    emailElem.click()
```

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? Does the program crash? Do you get an error message? Does it click the wrong element?

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry about the ambiguity, I get errors like this 
 ./fsu.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fsu.py", line 20, in <module>
    emailElem.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: If you get "'list' object has no attribute click", that sounds like you're calling 'find_elements_by_whatever' (notice the "s"). That returns a list of elements rather than a single element. Are you certain you are calling "find element_*" and not "find_elements_*"? Can you please show the exact code and the exact error by editing your question?

Answer (score 2):

"by class name" locator should be used to locate elements by *class attribute* values, in this case use "by id" or "by name" instead:

```
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('SSR_DUMMY_RECV1$sels$0')
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_name('SSR_DUMMY_RECV1$sels$0')
```

Comment: Thank you for responding!
Unfortunately I got this error: 

        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fsu.py", line 20, in <module>
    emailElem.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: @user6581117 you are using `find_elements_by_*` but need to use `find_element_*` method - watch the `s`.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I corrected it but still continue to receive this error.
         'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"SSR_DUMMY_RECV1$sels$0"}'

Answer (score 0):

Just add a bit more to alecxe's answer.

You need to be sure that its `id` and `name` are unique.

If they are not unique, you can add more attributes to `find by` methods, e.g.

```
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='SSR_DUMMY_RECV1$sels$0'][class=''PSRADIOBUTTON][type='radio']")
```

The more attributes you use, the more likely you will locate a unique element.

Comment: Thank you for responding! 
Unfortunately I continue to get this error 
            raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector input[id='SSR_DUMMY_RECV1$sels$0'][class=''PSRADIOBUTTON][type='radio'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments to the original question, you claim you're getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "./fsu.py", line 20, in <module> 
   emailElem.click() 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

That sounds like you're calling one of the `get_elements_*` functions rather than `get_element_*` (note the plural `elements`).

Error messages carry a lot of information in them, and need to be taken literally. Your error message is telling you that a list doesn't have a click method, which is true. Reading between the lines it means that the object on which you're calling `.click()` is a list, even though you think it is an element.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bryan Oakley! Is there any way to select it? From the [Selenium Docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=radio#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_selected) I gather that it must be `is_selected()` But I'm not sure how to implement that

Comment: @user6581117: does the following answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21322116/7432

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[type='radio']"}` I tried several of the answers but none seem to work and I continue to get a similar variation of this error.

Comment: Also received this error `emailElem = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='SSR_DUMMY_RECV1$sels$0']")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range` at one point but changing the index didn't solve it either. I greatly appreciate your help though :)