# Select radio button value with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have a page with source code like the sample below.  The page has a radio button with 5 values to select from.  I’m trying to check the box for “Value One.”  I’ve tried all the attempts below but haven’t had any luck with them.

I have also tried everything in the similar post:
[Using Selenium in Python to click/select a radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322116/using-selenium-in-python-to-click-select-a-radio-button)

but none worked for me.

Does anyone see what the issue is and can suggest how to solve it?

source:

```
<div class="col-sm-11">
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="questionaire3" value="Value One">Value One </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

code:

```
# driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[input type='radio'][value='Value One']").click()
# driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='Value One']").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='questionaire3'][value='Value One']").click()
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-e1d0a5c5435d> in <module>()
      7 # driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='Value One']").click()
      8 
----> 9 driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='questionaire3'][value='Value One']").click()

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element_by_css_selector(self, css_selector)
    595             element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#foo')
    596         """
--> 597         return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
    598 
    599     def find_elements_by_css_selector(self, css_selector):

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    964         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    965             'using': by,
--> 966             'value': value})['value']
    967 
    968     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    318         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    319         if response:
--> 320             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    321             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    322                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[name='questionaire3'][value='Value One']"}
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.109)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

Update:

this worked

driver.find_element_by_name("questionaire3").send_keys('Value One')

Comment: Can you share the URL of the page that you're trying to scrape?

Comment: The value is "Value One "... note the space at the end, `value="Value One "`. Your attempts are missing that space.

Comment: @JeffC thanks for pointing that out, the space was a type-o.  I corrected it in the original post.

Comment: Is this element in an IFRAME?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("questionaire3").send_keys('Value One')
```