# How could I select from RadioButtons using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I tried this code to select a radio button:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.asiamiles.com/en/enrolment.html')

gender = driver.find_element_by_id("gender_Female")
gender.click()
```

I received this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Where could the problem be, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322116/using-selenium-in-python-to-click-select-a-radio-button

Comment: The label is hiding the input field. try clicking on the label using xpath - //label[contains(.,'Female')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the *radio button* for *female* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.asiamiles.com/en/enrolment.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"label[for='gender_Female']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.asiamiles.com/en/enrolment.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='gender_Female']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: female]

Answer (score 0):

Reason for getting `ElementNotInteractableException` is that the radio button coordinates are x=0 and y=0, so selenium is not able to click.

[image]

Please use this below approach.

imports needed:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Script:

```
url = 'https://www.asiamiles.com/en/enrolment.html'
driver.get(url)
female = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.radio-label.bodytext4.F')))
female.location_once_scrolled_into_view
female.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

only using `id` it wont work when you hover on `label` tag it shows shaded region of the radio button that's where you need to click. for addition to that it takes a while to load a page so for smooth action use action class and it will click on element.

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)

gender = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@name='gender']/following-sibling::label[@for='gender_Female']") 
actions.move_to_element(gender).perform()
```