# Selenium - How select this button in "type=radio"

Tags: python, selenium

```
<li>
  <input type="radio" id="financial_data_0" 
   name="financial_d" data-dependson="[]" value="1">

        <label for="financial_data_0">
          ::before
               " Yes "
          ::after    
        </label>
<\li>
```

Hi guys, from this html above, I am trying to select the button "yes", in the following way, but it does not work:

`driver.find_element_by_id("financial_data_0").click()`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322116/using-selenium-in-python-to-click-select-a-radio-button/21322160

Comment: I have tried, but unfortunately it does not works in my case.. @BuddyBob

Comment: What does not work? The click or finding the element?

Comment: Try clicking the label driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//label[@for='financial_data_0']").click() .

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Man, you are my new super hero :DDD