# SELECT option from dropdown using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, system

been dealing with a countries dropdown using Selenium Python;

here is the Div tag of the drop-down menu:

`<div cdk-overlay-origin="" class="mat-select-trigger ng-tns-c95-29"><div class="mat-select-value ng-tns-c95-29" id="mat-select-value-1"><span class="mat-select-placeholder mat-select-min-line ng-tns-c95-29 ng-star-inserted"></span><!----><!----></div><div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper ng-tns-c95-29"><div class="mat-select-arrow ng-tns-c95-29"></div></div></div><!---->`

and here is the Div tag for the targeted option:

`<div class="mat-select-value ng-tns-c95-29" id="mat-select-value-1"><!----><span class="mat-select-value-text ng-tns-c95-29 ng-star-inserted" style=""><span class="mat-select-min-line ng-tns-c95-29 ng-star-inserted">MAROKO</span><!----><!----></span><!----></div><div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper ng-tns-c95-29"><div class="mat-select-arrow ng-tns-c95-29"></div></div>`

and here's the specific Span Tag for the targeted option

`<span class="mat-select-min-line ng-tns-c95-29 ng-star-inserted">MAROKO</span><!----><!---->`

the code used to select an option from that dropdown is :

```
Country=browser.find_element(By.ID, 'mat-select-value-1')
time.sleep(5) 
drop=Select(Country) 
time.sleep(5) 
drop.select_by_visible_text("MAROKO")
```

output

```
Exception has occurred: UnexpectedTagNameException
Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>
  File "C:\Users\test\form.py", line 31, in <module>
    drop=Select(Country)
```

I went with **drop.select_by_visible_text** since I believe it's the only available option!

Imports used

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
```

I would appreciate any helpful comment.

Cheers

[Tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322116/using-selenium-in-python-to-click-select-a-radio-button)
specifcly this;

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="mat-radio-2"]/label/span[1]/span[1][text()='MAROKO']"))).click()
```

but it seems that there's a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the selenium's `Select()` class only for html `<select>` tags. But this dropdown is implemented with `<div>`, so you can handle it just like html elements.
First you need to click the dropdown to expand the options and then click the option you need:

```py
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="mat-select-trigger ng-tns-c95-29"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'mat-select-value-1'))).click()
```

I've created the locators using the html parts you provided. Perharps you will need to update them.

Comment: it works perfectly, I had to change only the second locator's ID
Thanks